# I want to display repeated items in list only once and remove others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I want to display repeated items in list only once and the items those are not repeated want to remove from list, what should be the right procedure? Consider following function:

```
{
    alert("Hello");
    var symptomname = $('#symptomname').val();

    $.getJSON('http://54.148.253.123/HHS_Service/HealthService.svc/DiseaseGetBySymptom', { SymptomName: symptomname }, function (data) {


        var tasks = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        alert(tasks);
        $.each(tasks, function (key, value) {

            $('<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed="true"><h3>' + value.DiseaseName +
         '</h3><ul data-role="listview" id="search1ListView" data-inset="true" data-theme="a"><li><strong>Detail:</strong><span> '
          + value.Descr +
         '</span></li></ul></div>').appendTo('#foundDisease');

            // refreshing collapsible created dynamically "its necessary to refresh for a jQuery look and feel"
            $('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({ theme: 'a', refresh: true });

            $("#clear").click(function () {
                $("#foundDisease").empty();
            });
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: to remove duplicates from an array you can use [.unique()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using something like this:

```
 var tasks = $.parseJSON(data.d);
tasks=$.unique(tasks);// this should remove duplicate records.
```

then your loop starts.